# Padrão de Projeto Command não tem propósito em Python?

Tags: python, design-pattern

O Padrão de projeto Command fornece uma forma de desacoplar dois objetos,  aquele que invoca uma ação daquele que sabe como executa-lá, mas minha dúvida é : 
Em python e outras linguagens que funções são objetos de primeira classe qual a utilidade do Command ?

Comment: Se a própria linguagem já faz, por que reinventar? Se não me engano `iterator` é um padrão de projeto que não há muito sentido de se usar em Python visto a existência dos geradores. Não se esqueça que padrão de projeto é uma gambiarra padronizada institucionalizada e repetível. E como toda gambiarra, tem um propósito específico, normalmente de oferecer algo que não é nativo da linguagem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem, vou contribuir com o pouco de experiência que tenho, pois já vi em pouquíssimos casos este tipo de design, devido a pouca necessidade do mesmo (conforme já mencionado pelo Jefferson).

A princípio, o Python basicamente já tem uma função de command built-in, que é a seguinte (Exemplo extraído do stack overflow em inglês - [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494442/general-command-pattern-and-command-dispatch-pattern-in-python) ):

```
def greet(who):
      print "Hello %s" % who

greet_command = lambda: greet("World")
greet_command()
```

No entanto, eu já vi aplicações utilizando o pattern "Comando" em ocasiões de:

- Os comandos necessitarem realizar mais do que simplesmente executarem
  uma função básica/invocados;
- Maior legibilidade em alguns casos extensos.

É óbvio, no entanto, que os casos de comandos são muitas vezes casos de um método único e de simples/execução direta, deixando qualquer abordagem diferente do primeiro bloco de código desnecessária.

O próprio post do Stackoverflow em inglês realiza um bom exemplo, como em casos que você necessite realizar ações e eventualmente reverte-las:

```
Class ComandoGenerico():
     def __init__(self, destino, origem):
           self.origem = origem
           self.destino = destino
           #primeira alteração
           os.rename(self.origem, self.destino)

     #função para desfazer o comando inicial
     def desfazer(self):
           os.rename(self.destino, self.origem) #reverte para a condição inicial do comando


pilha = []
pilha.append(ComandoGenerico("oi.csv", "tudo_bem.csv")) #Arquivo renomeado para "tudo_bem.csv"
pilha.append((ComandoGenerico("tudo_bem.csv", "okay.csv")) #Arquivo renomeado para "okay.csv"

pilha.pop().desfazer() #Comando desfeito - Arquivo renomeado para "tudo_bem.csv"
pilha.pop().desfazer() #Comando desfeito - Arquivo renomeado para "oi.csv"
```

Comment: Obrigado Nicolas Vieira